# Microsoft Paint Spraypaint Tool

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

The following question is motivated by the spraypaint tool in Microsoft Paint.  In a sense, I'm asking how many clicks on average are necessary to fill each pixel within the range of the tool if we leave the cursor fixed.  The following is a more precise statement of the question:

> Consider $n$ dice, each with $k$ sides.  A roll consists of rolling all $n$ dice.  Determine $E(n,k)$, the expected number of rolls needed so that all numbers $1,\ldots,k$ have appeared on some roll.

The translation to spraypaint can be seen by assuming the range of the spraypaint tool is $k$ pixels, and each click paints $n$ random pixels.

I remember looking at this problem years ago, and only partially solving it.  I believe I worked on the case $n=1$:

$$E(1,k)=kH_k=k\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i}$$

Here $H_k$ is the $k$th harmonic number.  I'm not entirely convinced of this result.  For $n=2$ I could only find a closed form for asymptotic behavior as $k$ got large.  My memory of the solution is a bit fuzzy though.

Comment: For $n=1$, this is the well-known coupon collector's problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem, and your result is correct

Comment: There is a difference between the simultaneous dice rolls, where duplicates can happen, and the spraypaint as described, where the $n$ pixels are presumably distinct.  The latter is more like the coupon collector's problem variant with packets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \gt 1$ you can imagine the die rolls in a batch of $n$ are sequential.  Except for the last roll, the situation is the same, so $E(n,k) \approx \frac 1nE(1,k)$.  It will actually be a little higher than this, as you will (in effect) keep rolling up to the next multiple of $n$, when with $n=1$ you would quit.  The heuristic answer would be that on average you would waste half the rolls, so $E(n,k) \approx \frac 1nE(1,k)+\frac 12$.  To do better, I think you would have to assess the probability of completion at each multiple of $n$.